# Python Proper Way To Use Asyncio For Non-Async Functions

Tags: python, python-asyncio

here's my code example, that code works for windows, however I'm unsure that I use asyncio proper way, I would like to understand my mistakes.

```
from pytesseract import image_to_string
from PIL.ImageGrab import grab
from msvcrt import getch
from asyncio import run
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

async def string(data):
    return data

async def main():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        executor.submit(print, await string('Waiting for keypress to start OCR current screen . . .'))
        executor.submit(getch)
        executor.submit(print, await string('Starting OCR current screen . . .'))
        executor.submit(print, image_to_string(image=grab(), lang='chi_sim+eng'))
        executor.submit(print, await string('OCR process has been finished . . .'))


run(main())
```

Comment: Your suspicions are correct. You are not using asyncio correctly. `await` is a blocking operation so your code executes sequentially. On top of that the only difference between `await loop.run_in_executor(None, getch)` and `getch()` is that the former has the overhead of using a thread. None of your code seems I/O bound except for `getch`, which isn't asyncio-aware, so asyncio won't provide any value here. If you want to run `getch` in a way that doesn't block your main thread, take a look at `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Comment: @dirn, thanks, so I wonder do I use it right way now?

Comment: It’s really hard to help you use asyncio correctly because it provides no benefit to the examples you’ve posted. You could remove async, await, and the executor and your code would behave the same as what you’ve written. In fact it will be slightly faster because you’ll have removed the overhead of an event loop and threads. Why are you trying to use asyncio?

Comment: Asyncio is not a magic! Or is any concurrency frameworks. Async concurrency is best used for IO bottlenecks, otherwise thread or multiprocess would be preferrable.